# Change StatusBar color before Android 5.0

Tags: android

I know that the status-bar color can be the same as the `ActionBar`. However, I have no idea how to achieve this function before Android 5.0. I tried some features on the internet, but they did not work. If you know the answer, please tell me. Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/jgilfelt/SystemBarTint

Answer (score 1):

Use [SytemBarTint](https://github.com/jgilfelt/SystemBarTint) library to achieve this which has compatibility as follow

```
 <uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="10"
android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SystemBarTint](https://github.com/jgilfelt/SystemBarTint) or simply copy the static factory method below and call it in `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` in your `Activity`:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public static void setStatusBarColor(Activity activity, int color) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        activity.getWindow().setStatusBarColor(color);
    } else {
        try {
            ViewGroup decorViewGroup = (ViewGroup) activity.getWindow().getDecorView();
            View statusBarView = new View(activity);
            Resources res = activity.getResources();
            int id = res.getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
            LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    res.getDimensionPixelSize(id));
            params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
            statusBarView.setLayoutParams(params);
            statusBarView.setBackgroundColor(color);
            decorViewGroup.addView(statusBarView);
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
            // status-bar color cannot be changed.
        }
    }
}
```